# How can I connect NHibernate to multiple database servers within the same HttpRequest?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an ASP.NET 4 web application (MVC 4 release candidate, NHibernate 3, Fluent-NHibernate) that needs to read data from two different databases (each on a different server) during the same HttpRequest. I have two repositories:  IndividualRepository and ProductRepository. The Individual repository is read-only and connects to database A; the products repository is read/write and connects to database B. Both databases have a connection string in web.config.

My strategy before this "multiple database servers" requirement was imposed on me was to wire up an HttpModule with a static `SessionFactoryProvider<WebSessionContext>`. It had a static method "GetCurrentSession" that returns `ISession` via sessionFactoryProvider.GetCurrentSession(). Then on BeginRequest I call `sessionFactoryProvider.Bind()`, and on EndRequest I call `sessionFactoryProvider.Unbind()`.

With the addition of the second database server, my plan was to create a second static `SessionFactoryProvider<WebSessionContext>` and corresponding GetCurrentSession method.

For testing puropses, I have 2 NUnit tests (1 for each repository), and I have a similar setup with session factory providers, this time using `SessionFactoryProvider<ThreadStaticSessionContext>`.  I suspect that using ThreadStatic as the session context is part of the problem here, but I can't test both repositories.  I haven't been able to get my tests working, so I haven't tried the actual web application.

Am I just writing my tests wrong? Should I be using something other than `ThreadStaticSessionContext` for my integration tests?  I've been able to get each of my test methods working in issolation, but only 1 works when both session factory providers are included. Once I get my tests working, will I have a similar problem using two factory providers with the `WebSessionContext` in my web app?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question - yes, it is possible to connect to multiple DB servers using NHibernate within a single HTTP request.

I use it myself, however I apparently have a different session management from the one you use. I don't bind the sessions in `BeginRequest()`, instead I use an IoC container and retrieve a `ISessionBuilder` via a controller's constructor and then request the session via `sessionBuilder.GetSession()`.

That said, I suspect the solution to your problem will be similar to the one I have wired up. Basically, instead of having a single `ISessionFactory`, I keep a dictionary of them (keyed by the DB server identifier).

If this does not lead you to a viable solution, you may have to provide the code of your `SessionFactoryProvider`.

Comment: Thanks! I was starting to think I was going crazy when I couldn't get it working.  I haven't gone as far as to keep a dictionary of session factories, but I was able to prove it out using two static instances of ISessionFactory.  I also had to change the session context I was using from ThreadStatic to ThreadLocal.